# How to use Google Calendar from within Sharepoint?

Tags: wss-3.0

I want to use my Google Calendar within Sharepoint.

Is there a webpart available for this?

I use WSS 3.0

Saumil

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use either the Page Viewer web part, or the Content Editor web part. When using the CEWP, switch to the source (HTML) view and insert the code to embed the Google calendar.

Comment: thx rob, never knew GCal provides sucha deep customizations!!

Comment: how to retrieve data from Google calendar ??

Answer (score 1):

Follow this link to learn how to embed the Calendar on another website, then use one of the methods Rob describes to actually embed it in a web part page.

http://www.google.com/support/calendar/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=41207

Comment: thx james for the link

Comment: Hi James This is working fine but if Sign out from Gmail its doesn't work. can i use calender without Gmail login ?

Answer (score 1):

[SharePoint Calendar Rollup](http://www.boostsolutions.com/calendar-rollup.html) is a web part which allows users to aggregate Google Calendar to SharePoint Calendar. But so far, this web part only enables to pull data from Google Calendar into SharePoint calendar. Not sure what kind how do you decide to use Google calendar within SharePoint though.